# How do I extract the filename of a URL in a ASP.NET Core MVC "To Do" app and show it to the user in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC `To Do` app. When I start the app, the app has a default URL of `https://localhost` but how do I get the `filename` from a URL like this one `https://localhost/14-11-2020`. I need to get the `14-11-2020` as parameter and display it in a `.cshtml` file between `<time></time>` tags as `14 / 11 / 2020`. Each time the user changes the date, it needs to show the tasks from that date (since this is a "TODO" app). I have already setup the model with a database with `DateTime` attribute.

My question is that: how do I extract the filename of a URL and show it to the user in the View?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I extract the filename of a URL and show it to the user in the
> View?

The **AbsolutePath** property contains the path information that the server uses to resolve requests for information in C#. [(More Details)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absolutepath?view=netcore-3.1)

passing data to view from controller [(more details)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#passing-data-to-views)
I am using **ViewData** here,

> ViewData is a ViewDataDictionary object accessed through string keys.
> String data can be stored and used directly without the need for a
> cast, but you must cast other ViewData object values to specific types
> when you extract them. You can use ViewData to pass data from
> controllers to views and within views, including partial views and
> layouts.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
      Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
      string name = Path.GetFileName(myUri.AbsolutePath);
      ViewData["FileName"] = name;
      return View();
    }
```

For the Path class use namespace **using System.IO;**
and inside view use,

```
<title>@ViewData["FileName"] - WebApplication</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url params from the method on the controller

```cs
public class ToDoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{date:DateTime}")]
    public IActionResult Index(DateTime date)
    {
        //// filter by date

        return View();
    }
}
```

In the above example a url of http://localhost:1234/todo/01-01-2020 would pass a date time of '01/01/2020 00:00:00' into the todo controller method

Comment: The example in the question isn't with a query string...

Comment: updated the answer to parse out the url data in the controller method

Answer (score 0):

Get the date from RouteData and store it in ViewBag or ViewDate in controller, then access it the view:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string date = RouteData.Values.Values.LastOrDefault().ToString();
    var mydate = date.Replace("-", "/");
    ViewBag.CurrentDate = mydate;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<time>@ViewBag.CurrentDate</time>
```